# Could would give

Tags: word-choice

When answering the question "what situation would give you butterflies?"
Can I use either "would" or "could" in in my sentence? Is there any difference in meaning?

1."I don't know what kind of situation would/could  give me butterflies."

2." I don't know how  a situation would/could  give me butterflies?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a situation *would* give you butterflies, you are sure that it would.

If it *could* give you butterflies, you think it is possible that it might.

Comment: so the sentences are correct as they are written, aren't they?